# Showing that a sequence of function converge with subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Most examples that I have read apply continuity argument to limit question like this:

$$L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(1/n) = \sin(\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n) = \sin(0) = 0$$

Clearly the sine function is continuous. But then it comes to me that if we let $n = \frac{1}{2\pi k}$, we can construct new subsequence $\sin(2\pi k$), which for integer $k$ is always null, thus the original sequence must be null as well.

My question is, ist this the valid way of constructing new subsequence? (Adding a factor of $2\pi$)?

Thank You

Comment: If $\displaystyle n=\frac{1}{2\pi k}$ then $n$ does not go to infinity...

Comment: That was my bad example. But still, is there any other possibility of approaching this problem with the creation of subsequence?

Comment: Say Let $ n = k/(2\pi k^2+1)$.

Comment: $$\sin( \frac{2\pi k^2 + 1}{k} ) = \sin( 2 \pi k + \frac{1}{k} ) = \sin( 2 \pi k ) \cos(1/k) + \sin(1/k) \cos( 2 \pi k) = \sin(1/k)$$

Comment: Right, thanks for showing the point. I seem to make a whole new question all together with that...

Comment: **@Jp McCarthy:** You can't use $n=\frac{1}{2\pi k}$  because $n\in\mathbb N$ and $\frac{1}{2\pi k}\notin\mathbb N$.

Comment: @idm This is moot and you don't have to take $n\in \mathbb{N}$ to do make sense of $n\rightarrow \infty$ here.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a subsequence is always null wouldn't mean a sequence is null as well. For example, consider the sequence $(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3\cdots)$ and the subsequence $(0,0,0,0\cdots)$